# Create a View in SQL with a Concatenated Column > Then use Case Statement to affect values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I created a view with a concatenated column named **DisplayName**, using the code below.

```
create view DisplayNames as 
    select FirstName + ' ' + LastName DisplayName,
           *
    from Table1
```

Is there a way to change specific **DisplayName** values using a case statement (or a better method)

Something like:

case
when DisplayName = 'Robert Jones' THEN 'Bob Jones'
when DisplayName = 'Thomas Simms' THEN 'Tommy Simms'

or

when FirstName = 'Robert' AND LastName = 'Jones' THEN 'Bob Jones'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would suggest `APPLY`:

```
create view DisplayNames as 
    select (case when v.DisplayName = 'Bob Jones' then'Thomas Simms'
                 else v.DisplayName
            end) as DsiplayName,
           t1.*
    from Table1 t1 cross apply
         (values (FirstName + ' ' + LastName)) v(DisplayName);
```

This allows you to define the column in the `FROM` clause.  Then you don't need to figure out how to remove the old value -- as would be necessary with a CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
create view DisplayNames as 
select
    case FirstName 
        when 'Robert' then 'Bob'
        when 'Thomas' then 'Tommy'
    end 
    + ' ' 
    + LastName DisplayName,
    t.*
from Table1 t
```

This applies the transcodification to the first name separately, regardless of the last name.